# Accessing VMWare Management Network from a different subnet

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, subnet

Here's the scenario...

We've got a VSphere ESXi 5 box running on a 9.x subnet, our office runs from the 1.x subnet. We can access the VM's running on the box without issue (which also have 9.x IP's) however we can ping the management network interface for the VM box but can't either browse to the box http/https nor use VSphere client to connect to it. The connection just times out. We have a VPN connection between the two subnets and have checked both firewalls and nothing is being blocked (which is also supported by the fact that all traffic can pass to/from the VM's).

Is there a setting within VMWare that restricts management traffic by default, to its local subnet? It would make sense for that to be the case...but I can't find any options within VSphere client. The default gateway is definitely correct for the management network, again supported by the fact that we can ping and get a response from its IP from our 1.x network.

If anyone has any suggestions, they would be kindly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps if you articulate exactly what IP addresses and netmasks both the server and the system you are attempting to connect from have, along with their default routes, we might be able to better assist in troubleshooting.

Answer (score 5):

This isn't anything whatsoever to do with vSphere, it's a simple Layer 3 routing issue, get some working routing in place, that's it.

Comment: All traffic between the two subnets including L3 is routing fine, apart from traffic to/from the VMWare management network. Surely if it was a L3 routing issue at the firewalls nothing (L3) would be able to traverse the connection?

Comment: Does no one have any other thoughts on this? I don't think it's a layer 3 routing issue as all traffic is routed between the two subnets...it's literally just managing this VMWare box that is causing us problems.

Comment: It's not a terribly clearly-written question to be honest - have you tried connecting from inside the same vlan? that'll tell you if it's a server or network issue right?

Comment: My apologies...everything within the same VLAN works fine (incl VMWare Mgmt). Everything between VLAN's works fine...APART from connecting to the VMWare management network. We can connect fine to other hosts on that VLAN/subnet without issue. The only thing we can't access on that particular VLAN is the VMWare Management Network...servers on that VLAN can be accessed fine. Not sure if that makes it any clearer? If we were having other L3 issues when accessing this subnet I would agree that it points towards routing, but it's literally just VMWare

Comment: Right, so it all works inside the same vlan, have you checked the netmask & gateway on your esxi server? maybe it's not right and it's not got a valid way out of that vlan? other than that I guess it's just a basic L2/L3 routing/firewall/client config issue - there's no option in esxi to just allow connections from its own vlan, unless the netmask/gateway is wrong.

Comment: I'm afraid so, that was my first guess. Gateway and subnet mask are both correct; it does seem odd that I can ping that interface. Everything is routed as it should be by the looks of the firewalls which is just routing everything over the VPN to our office.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but I've seen this problem before and wanted to help any other vsphere admins who run into the same issue. When you can manage the esxi environment from the local subnet but not from a remote, the trouble is going to be a layer 3 or higher issue. Since other traffic can traverse from one subnet to another you know the problem isn't in the router or firewalls in between. So the problem must be on the esxi device. The situation you have described can easily occur if a VKERNAL adapter is set up to belong do a different IP range than is correct. You can verify this easily by navigating to **Host -> Manage -> Networking -> TCP/IP configuration _> IPv4 routing table**. If you see that the host is trying to locally route (gateway 0.0.0.0) to a subnet that it is not a part of then you have found your culprit. Track down the vkernal adapter that is misconfigured and get it configured correctly!

Answer (score 1):

@Jacob Maron. This was exactly the problem. THANKS

In my case, there was not gateway configured.thats why I could access it on the same network but not any other network (vpn, for example).

Right Click on the Host>Configuration>Networking>Properties>Management Network (you may have renamed your mgmt network something else)>Edit>Check the default gateway and subnet mask.

Comment: Yup this fixed my problem as well vSphere --> Host Configuration --> Networking -->(vSwitch with Management Network VMkernel Port) vSwitch0 --> Properties --> Management Network --> Edit… --> IP Settings --> VMkernel Default Gateway --> Edit… --> Gateway IP

Answer (score 0):

If it's not a layer 3 and the gateway is defined - Even though the IP settings look correct, select static and review (edit the gateway) then click okay, that will get it to respond.